# facebook messenger handover protocol take_thread_control

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es

i created a bot with messenger and dialogflow, This works good
but the problem comes when i try to implement the handover protocol

**First approach : *Pass thread control to PAGE INBOX***
i set up an intent on dialogflow with 'input.handover' action then when i type handover i call my webhook and make a call to fb api with pass_thread_control and i passe the control to the page inbox, i get a success response and the conversation pass from the **BOT** to **PAGE INBOX**. But here a stuck to **PAGE INBOX** and i cant take_thread_control to the **BOT** because the **PAGE INBOX** not linked with the dialogflow or any other webhook.

**Second approach : *Pass thread control to another app***
with the same setup of first approach but this time i pass the thread control to a facebook **APP** i created and linked with a webhook (with nodejs hosted on heroku), i get a success response but this time no message come to this **APP** inbox and on heroku console i can see the message come to webhook but not **APP** inbox.

And now i just stuck here. if any one have an idea how to implement the handover protocol with dialogflow or any help, i appreciate that.

**Thanks.**

Comment: same I also stuck on your 1st approach but i have the solution can't post as an answer because of its long code tell me supposed way to contact you

Comment: Thanks @NikhilSavaliya, my email fahmichaar@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

ok i just find a workaround by mixing the two approaches

**step 1** : with the second app subscribe your webhook to the bot page
[page_subscribe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c7nw.jpg)

**step 2** : the second app webhook is just for take the thread control back to primary app when the user type a special keyword like (exit or back...)

```
app.post('/webhook', (request, response) => {
    const webhook_events = request.body.entry[0];
    // console.log('webhook_events : ', webhook_events);

    // Secondary Receiver is in control - listen on standby channel
    if (webhook_events.standby) {

        // iterate webhook events from standby channel
        webhook_events.standby.forEach(event => {

            const psid = event.sender.id;
            const message = event.message;

            // check if the user want back to the bot
            if (message && (message.text == 'exit' || message.text == 'back')) {

                // HandoverProtocol.takeThreadControl is just call the facebook api to takeThreadControl
                HandoverProtocol.takeThreadControl(psid).then(reps => {

                    // replay.sendMessage also call facebook api to send a message to the user to let him know he is back chat with the bot 
                    replay.sendMessage(psid, 'Hi, your are back to the BOT');

                }).catch(err => console.log(err));
            }

        });   
    }

    // respond to all webhook events with 200 OK
    response.sendStatus(200);
})
```

now all user messages pass from the second app webhook and when he type 'back' for example the webhook take the control back to the primary app (the bot in this case)